# How to redo the js when the datatables responsive function triggers

Tags: javascript, triggers, datatables, responsive

I want to make some js function to the table
just like

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
});

$(".point").html('hello');
```

But when the windows resize and the responsive function work 
it cannot redo the js function.

even I use

```
table.on( 'draw', function () {
  console.log( 'Redraw occurred at: '+new Date().getTime() );
  $(".point").html('hello');
} );
```

still cannot redo the js. How can I trigger the function redo when the responsive trigger?

https://jsfiddle.net/housekeepings/v8x9wn03/34/

Comment: I just tried the jsfiddle, and I think it does work for me, at least partially. Column 'Office' shows 'hello'. When I make the jsfiddle window smaller though, it shows 'Origin DATA' again. Tried in latest Firefox. It doesn't print anything into the console, so I assume only your first piece of code does anything.

Comment: Btw., my answer is derived from here - so I think the question was already answered in a different post.

Comment: @ErikReder That's the question, I had make the 'Origin DATA' change to 'hello' But  when the responsive happend(duo to the windows size change) ,it still shows the 'origin Data' not the 'hello'. So I think I  must redo the $(".point").html('hello') again . But I don't know where to write the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the window resize event:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    console.log( 'Redraw occurred at: '+new Date().getTime() );
    $(".point").html('hello'); 
});
```

Comment: it cannot work when  I type this on the jsfiddle example

Comment: Hmm, works well for me - replace the whole script part with the code above. Text shows as 'Origin DATA' initially - upon window resizing it changes to 'hello' and console prints e.g. this:
Redraw occurred at: 1550487962960
Redraw occurred at: 1550487971940...

Comment: @robspin - in case you just downvoted my answer (without further comment to my reply) - did you try and replace the whole script part in jsfiddle with my code above. It really does work for me - if it doesn't for you, then maybe there's some completely different issue.